# How to edit HTML, CSS code inline in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, inline, edit

Could somebody tell me how to change (or even find a file with), this code in wordpress?

[image: printscreen from Inspect Element (Q) about my site]

I know what to change but I have no idea how. 
I've already checked:

- All of the *.css files in my themes?
- All of the *.php files.
- And this is not in a Visual Editor in WP.

How to do it?

Comment: This could be a 3rd party widget code. The element it's in is called `widget_getresponse-widget`, so check which widget is assigned to the first widget place for this page, and then you'll know what to inspect.

Comment: As @dingo_d already wrote in a comment, this seems to be some code from a widget (judging by its parent element), and probably you won't be able to change that automatically generated code. Since it's inline CSS (probably dynamically added by a script), you also won't be able to overwrite it with custom CSS. The only way I can think of is to get into the settings/code of that widget and change that script, but that's a tough challenge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a one class that needs it's properties changed go to the visual editor and override the inline style with **!important** rule, like this:

```
.content {
  min-height: 150px !important;
}
```

Also be careful when using !important - [it should be used sparingly](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

Comment: just `.content` would be to broad and could break things up. Better target with some longer selector like `.widget_getresponse-widget .content{...}`